# Configuring Log4j2.properties with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2

Is it possible on Spring Boot 1.5.2 to use log4j2 property configuration as opposed to xml?

The logging documentation over on the official spring docs seems to indicate only xml is supported.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html

Answer (score 10):

Yes you can. In my case I couldn't get Spring Boot to find my `log4j2.properties`. I had to specify inside `application.properties`:

```
logging.config=src/main/resources/log4j2.properties
```

Whereas I didn't have to do that if I had `log4j2.xml` in the same folder

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It is possible. I am working in a microservice environment using Spring Boot 1.5.2 and for logging LOG4j2.

First, you need to remove the spring logging feature and add log4j2 dependencies.

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Create log4j2.properties file and declare all the required configuration like:

```
name = ABC 
appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
appender.rolling.fileName = ABClog/ABCapplication.log
appender.rolling.filePattern = ABClog/ABCapplication.%d{dd-MMM}.log
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %level [%t] [%c] [%M] [%l]- %msg%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy 
appender.rolling.strategy.action.type = Delete 
appender.rolling.strategy.action.basepath =log 
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.type = IfFileName
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.glob = ABC*.log
appender.rolling.strategy.action.ifAny.type = IfAny
appender.rolling.strategy.action.ifAny.ifLastModified.type = IfLastModified
appender.rolling.strategy.action.ifAny.ifLastModified.age = 14d
appender.rolling.strategy.action.ifAny.ifAccumulatedFileSize.type = IfAccumulatedFileSize
appender.rolling.strategy.action.ifAny.ifAccumulatedFileSize.exceeds = 200MB
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
logger.rolling.name = com.currentobject.controller
logger.rolling.level = debug
logger.rolling.additivity = false
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile
```

Provide the path of lo4j42.properties file into the application.properties file(resource folder)

```
logging.config=classpath:log4j2.properties
```

Comment the default logging properties of Spring boot in the application.properties file:

```
#logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
```